# JS Autocomplete - access label value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an autocomplete form box which displays a label, and then inserts a value once selected. I would like to use part of the label (client_id) to form part of the form post once it is submitted.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $( "#clientsearch" ).autocomplete({
  source: 'backend_search_addressWT.php',
  minLength: 2, 

  select: function (event, ui) {
    return showUser(ui.item.value)
    },

    change: function (event, ui) {
      return showUser(ui.item.value);
    },
 });
});
</script>
```

backend_search_addressWT.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'config.php';

    //get search term
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

    //get matched data from skills table
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_address LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = array (
            'label' => $row['client_address'].' - '.$row['client_name'].' - '.$row['client_id'],
            'value' => $row['client_address'],
            'value2' => $row['client_id'],
            );
    }

    //return json data
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I have tried adding this to the js, to no avail:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $( "#clientsearch" ).autocomplete({
  source: 'backend_search_addressWT.php',
  minLength: 2, 

  select: function (event, ui) {
    return showUser(ui.item.value);
    var label = (ui.item.label).split('-')
    var client_id = label[2]
    $('#hiddenID').client_id
    },

    change: function (event, ui) {
      return showUser(ui.item.value);
    },
 });
});
</script>
```

Notice that I already use a select callback on the value ui.

How can I access the label?

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: thanks for the heads up. still in development (and still beginner). if you could make a suggestion on how to improve the query with regards to sql injection, please do!

Comment: You can read the links I linked to in the comment (click on "Prepared Statements").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `select()` method you added code after the `return` statement:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
return showUser(ui.item.value);
var label = (ui.item.label).split('-')
var client_id = label[2]
$('#hiddenID').client_id
}
```

These lines will never be executed.

What do you expect `$('#hiddenID').client_id` to do for you? This will most likely achieve nothing, since it looks for a (probably not existing) property of a jquery element which it then discards again.

**Instead (edited)**:

Place the label processing instructions *before* the return statement and see what happens. Maybe start by showing the label in the console first and then putting it into a hidden input field:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
  console.log(ui.item.label); // just to make sure there is something to process ...
  $('#hiddenID').val(ui.item.label.split(' - ').pop());   // to place the last portion 
                 // of the label in that hidden element (assuming it is an input field)
  return showUser(ui.item.value);
}
```

The `.split(' - ').pop()` will return only the last element of the label string (assuming the components are separated by a `' - '` string).

Comment: this places the label into the hidden input field, but I only need the last value from this string. Should I try split it here?

Comment: @wazzahenry updated my answer accordingly. I hope it works for you.